# slice string with multiple delimiters

Tags: bash, unix, slice

I have numerous log files with target lines that I wish to 'grep', such as:

```
EGPA019_90pc.recode.2.log:Cross-Entropy (masked data):   0.556984
```

I wish to slice out the "2" and the "0.556984" spaced with a tab to a file

So, if I enter:

```
grep "Cross-Entropy (masked data):" *.log | cut -d '.' -f 3 >> targetFile.txt
```

I get the "2", and:

```
grep "Cross-Entropy (masked data):" *.log | cut -d ' ' -f 4 >> targetFile.txt
```

I get the "0.556984". But how can I write this in a single line of code to obtain the "2" then a tab then "0.556984" on the same line in my target file?

Many thanks

Clive

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` and a bit of `bash` built-in regEx feature.

```
grep -h "Cross-Entropy (masked data):" *.log | while IFS= read -r string; do
       [[ "$string" =~ .recode.([[:digit:]]+).*:\ (.*)$ ]] 
       printf "%s\t%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  "${BASH_REMATCH[2]//[[:blank:]]}";
done
```

My input files

```
$ cat *.log
EGPA019_90pc.recode.2.log:Cross-Entropy (masked data):   0.556984
EGPA019_90pc.recode.9.log:Cross-Entropy (masked data):   0.996984
EGPA019_90pc.recode.7.log:Cross-Entropy (masked data):   0.756984

$ grep -h "Cross-Entropy (masked data):" *.log | while IFS= read -r string; do
       [[ "$string" =~ .recode.([[:digit:]]+).*:\ (.*)$ ]] 
       printf "%s\t%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  "${BASH_REMATCH[2]//[[:blank:]]}"; done
2       0.556984
9       0.996984
7       0.756984
```

Explanation:-

1. Am using built-in `bash` regEx feature to capture the required string, instead of using other native tools.
2. The output of `grep` is piped to apply the regEx `[ "$string" =~ recode.([[:digit:]]+).*:\ (.*)$ ]]` which captures your required entries, a digit and the decimal number.
3. Using `printf` to print those variables. The 2nd capture, i.e. the decimal digits have whitespace characters in the beginning, removing it by `"${BASH_REMATCH[2]//[[:blank:]]}"`

You can also wrap it around in a shell script as below:-

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r string; do
    [[ "$string" =~ .recode.([[:digit:]]+).*:\ (.*)$ ]]
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"  "${BASH_REMATCH[2]//[[:blank:]]}"
done < <(grep -h "Cross-Entropy (masked data):" *.log)
```

Or) Use `grep` with PCRE flag `-P` option, and `xargs` to filter output.

```
grep -Pho '\.recode\.\K\d+|: \K.*' *.log | xargs -n2 -d'\n'
2   0.556984
9   0.996984
7   0.756984
```

(or) Use a much simpler `perl` regEx syntax.

```
perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if /\.recode\.(\d+).*:\s+(.*)/' *.log
2 0.556984
9 0.996984
7 0.756984
```

Comment: Hi, this just gives me a lot of white space without the info I want. Thanks

Comment: What is is printing:? Can you share the output? It worked fine for me in the example text you gave. Either you are invoking it incorrectly or your input lines are different

Comment: I have 10 lines in my input and I get 10 lines of whitespace back. Your input looks identical

Comment: EGPA019_90pc.recode.10.log:Cross-Entropy (masked data):  0.654632

Comment: Which shell are you in? It is working fine for me, can you show me `bash --version?`

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Comment: @user3329732: `bash` version looks fine, can you refer my update and try to run it as a script? and let me know

Comment: Hi again - still whitespace. I'm thinking it maybe the the '*.log' component. I grepped the lines from the files I was interested in into a single file called tmp.txt

Comment: Still whitespace - I'm not sure why

Comment: Is the grep first producing results properly? I think there is something wrong with invocation.

Comment: @user3329732: Added a `-h` option in `grep` which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd do this using `awk` rather than parsing the output of `grep`.

I don't have your dataset to test this on, but it seems to me that the following should work.

```
awk '/^Cross-Entropy \(masked data\):/ {split(FILENAME,a,".");printf("%s\t%s\n", a[3], $NF}' *.log
```

It's a bit long as a one-liner.  As a standalone script, it might look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^Cross-Entropy \(masked data\):/ {
  split(FILENAME,a,".")
  printf("%s\t%s\n", a[3], $NF
}
```

Save this in a file, make it executable, and you have yourself a brand new shell command.

Note that this works by using field splitting, NOT by using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove unwanted things with `sed`:

```
grep "Cross-Entropy (masked data):" *.log | sed 's/.*recode.//;s/\..*: //'
```

The `grep` and `sed` can be combined:

```
sed -n '/Cross-Entropy (masked data):/ {s/.*recode.//;s/\..*: //;p}' *.log
```